# Trouble with PHP and Cookie set as Variable

Tags: php, cookies

I have this script to check that a cookie is on the computer, and then use the info from that cookie to take someone to the right page on my website. Here is the code

```
<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
    $name = $_COOKIE["name"];
    header("location: names/$name/$name.php");
 else
    echo "You have no name"; 
?>
```

When this script is run, it does nothing. Not even echo "You have no name". Any ideas why this code won't work?

Comment: Curly braces are necessary if your block statement expands past one line

Comment: Without assuming, at any point prior to your code do you ever call `setcookie` and/or assign a value to the cookie to store? Have your cookies expired? Did you alter the cookie settings or leave them default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets.  Maybe you are used to python?

```
<?php
 if (isset($_COOKIE["name"])){
    $name = $_COOKIE["name"];
    header("location: names/$name/$name.php");
 }else{
    echo "You have no name"; 
 }
?>
```

The syntax error with else is probably causing the script to fail and you may have error reporting turned off.  Turn it on.